# Matlab : find and processing object in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image like this

I want to find the object of this image and processing that object.
here's my code

```
bw = im2bw(myImage);
bw = invertedBW(bw);
bw = bwperim(bw);
bwlabelimg = bwlabel(bw);
```

is possible to process each object in image?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  Just loop through each object and process it.  What you can do is create a mask that is equal to each unique label and process the mask.  I'm going to use the two-output version of `bwlabel` where the second output tells you **how many objects** we have.  Something like:

```
% // Your code
bw = im2bw(myImage);
bw = invertedBW(bw);
bw = bwperim(bw);
[bwlabelimg, num] = bwlabel(bw); %// Slightly modified

for idx = 1 : num %// For each object...
    mask = bwlabelimg == idx; %// Create mask that only contains the object

    %// Process your object, stored in the mask variable....

end
```